# scroll bar related position and animation

Tags: html, css, position

Trying to implement manual scroll styling. So far looks good, have only a couple issues thing I don't see the way to implement:
- need to shift the scroll handle from top, right and bottom on 3px distance
- need to make an animation that hides the scroll bar/handle when cursor is out of the scrolled zone.

Preferably in css of course(the app is restricted for google chrome >31 users).

[image]

CSS-code:

```
/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05); 
}
```